# Top (conditional) radio button always selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, selected

I currently pass some values over to one of my ascx.cs files, and it displays certain radio buttons depending on the value that is sent over. The radio buttons are instantiated in the .ascx side of things:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="length5yr" GroupName="SubLength" runat="server" Visible ="false"
             /> 
            <asp:label runat="server" id="Label5yr" Visible="false" style="width: 300px">
            </asp:label>


             <asp:RadioButton ID="length3yr" GroupName="SubLength" runat="server"  Visible ="false"
             />
            <asp:label runat="server" id="Label3yr" Visible="false" style="width: 300px">
            </asp:label>


     <asp:RadioButton ID="length2yr" GroupName="SubLength" runat="server"  Visible ="false"
             />
            <asp:label runat="server" id="Labelyr2" Visible="false" style="width: 300px">
            </asp:label>


     <asp:RadioButton ID="length1yr" GroupName="SubLength" runat="server"  Visible ="false"
             />
            <asp:label runat="server" id="Label1yr" Visible="false" style="width: 300px">

            </asp:label>

     <asp:RadioButton ID="lengthQuarterly" GroupName="SubLength" runat="server"  Visible ="false"
             />
            <asp:label runat="server" id="labelQuarterly" Visible="false" style="width: 300px">
            </asp:label>

    <asp:RadioButton ID="lengthMonthly" GroupName="SubLength" runat="server"  Visible ="false"
             />
            <asp:label runat="server" id="labelMonthly" Visible="false" style="width: 300px">
            </asp:label>
```

I want whichever radio button that ends up being the first/top one displayed to be checked. I've been able to get the last radio button checked (which also gives me other problems anyways) - but how can I get that top one checked!?

This is the code for how I determine which radio button is displayed - I have only shown one of the options just to make the code a little bit easier to read.

```
 foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in orderOptions)
        {
            if (d["length"] == "one")
            {
                length1yr.Visible = true;
                price1yr = d["price"];
                rate1yr = d["rate"];
                issues1yr = d["issues"];
                premium1yr = d["premium"];
                Label1yr.Text = d["description"] + "<br><br>";
                Label1yr.Visible = true;
                SubLength1yr = "1 year";

            }
```

Comment: How are you creating the radio buttons? Dynamically or are they all always there and just hidden based on some criteria?

Comment: AH, they're always there and just hidden based on the criteria.

Comment: Do you want a server-side of client-side solution? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: I don't suppose it really matters too much - as long as it gets the job done and I get something out of it, I am A-OK with the solution.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the HTML this spits out as well as the code you use to determine which radio button(s) to show?

Comment: I've only shown a portion of the logic, as I don't think the rest is necessary. As for the html, I'm not sure I can retrieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a server-side solution, the easiest would be to iterate over the list of `RadioButton` and use some simple LINQ to select the first visible button.

Something like:

```
var buttons = new []{length5yr, ...};
var firstVisibleButton = buttons.Where(b=>b.Visible).First();
firstVisibleButton.Checked = true;
```

The above is probably more pseudo-code than anything, but without a full code sample, that's all I can do. I am sure you can figure out the details. The above code would have to execute *after* you have hidden/shown the `RadioButton`.

I should probably specify that the list you create (*buttons*) **must** follow the order in which the buttons are displayed for this to work properly.

Comment: The problem with this, is that when I select something below the first radio button, it doesn't pass the correct data onto the next page :/ It always passes the data attached to the "first" radio button displayed.

Comment: What data are we talking about here?

Comment: Vague - I know. There's a method that gets run when someone clicks hte "submit" button that is on the same page as these radio buttons. Depending on which radio button is selected, it passes certain information. So when the button is pressed, if radiobutton1.checked, it sets certain values for x, y, and z variables and those are what end up getting passed. if radiobutton2.checked, those values will be different. In this case, radio button 2 (for example) is checked, but it's passing the values as if radio button 1 was still selected.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on ASP.net, but it sounds that you are doing some of this work "too early" in the ASP page cycle and the ViewState of the buttons has not been applied yet or something like that. If you want more help here, you might have to post a small code sample with more code (don't use your real code). Creating that smaller code sample might also help you get to the bottom of this by trying a smaller scope.